# Populate Excel table based on conditional options from another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

As seen below, I have an excel file where collections from debtors is recorded.

Column A is the staff code who made the collection..

Column B is the date of collection

Rest is self explanatory

[image]

Out of this table, on a different sheet, I need to extract data from this table and populate a new table with the filtered data. E.g., On the second sheet, I need a table to show collections from only P102, of which I have managed to do with the below array formula:

```
{=INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A:$A="P102",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A)))),ROWS(Sheet2!$A$2:$A2)))}
```

Of course this code outputs only the Personnel code but I've ammended this to show for other columns too..

The thing I can't manage to do is, I also need to apply a second filter with the date.. Eg. Only those records from P101 and only in February..

I would really appreciate any feedback on this...

P.S. I do not wish to use Macros and No, I can't make a pivot table...

Regards,

Kemal

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd approach it using an array formula with logical conditional multipliers. Very similar to SUMIFS.

Here's the output I understand you require:

[image: SOI20140621]

Here'e the array function (shift + ctrl + enter) I've used placed in cells G2:G5:

```
={SUM(IF(Table1[Personel]=E2,1,0)*IF("2014"&VLOOKUP(F2,{"Jan",1;"Feb",2;"Mar",3;"Apr",4;"May",5;"Jun",6;"Jul",7;"Aug",8;"Sep",9;"Oct",10;"Nov",11;"Dec",12},2,0)=TEXT(Table1[Date],"yyyym"),1,0)*Table1[Cash])}
```

Please indicate if there is anything further outstanding.

Kind regards,

James

Comment: Dear James, thank you for sparing your time on this but unfortunately this was not my required output. I have managed to do what I wanted and will post here once I am confident about the solution.